# How to swipe between multiple links in textview using talkback in android?

Tags: android, spannablestring, talkback, accessibility

I am trying to improve accessibility for a text view used for terms and privacy policy which looks something like this:

[image]

As mentioned on the [Google Support page](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6378148?hl=en), the user will need to access the `Local Context Menu` via a `TalkBack` gesture (default gesture is Swipe up then right) to activate a TextView link.

But I want to use a swipe gesture to navigate between links something like:
[image]

Currently, I am using clickable span to add the links, it is working fine with `Local Context Menu` but not with a swipe gesture.
My code looks something like this:

```
    val clickableSpan: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
            // handle link click.
        }
    }
    val spannableStringBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder(text).apply {
        setSpan(clickableSpan, 99, 109, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
    }
    tv_term_and_privacy_policy.apply {
        setText(spannableStringBuilder)
        movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    }
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Sure, would be helpful if you provide us some code.

Comment: code added for your reference.

Comment: Users using Talkback will know about local context menus, it is expected behaviour which will be pretty consistent across many different apps. It also allows the user to swipe past TextView quicker without making additional gestures if they chose not to open the links. I would recommend leaving the default behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, @sigute for your comment, but the swipe gesture is the requirement of the project.

Comment: You will most likely have to build a custom view to handle this type of interaction. One approach would be to have each element as a separate view in some sort of flow layout. Then links could be buttons and could have actions on them, but making the text flow correctly will be a big challenge.

Comment: I will definitely look into this.

Comment: @imvishi Did you get any solution?

Comment: @saurabh-padwekar - no, I didn't get the solution for this, so we decided to use the Local context menu for now.

Comment: Thanks for replying. We are also going with the same solution.